# Website not loading after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a site that I have been using without any issues for quite a while now. I've made some changes to improve performance, including storing data in the cache and altering how the site interacts with the database. However since publishing the site to it's location it is now just returning a blank page whenever I try to load it.

I am getting error emails from the site whenever I try to load it, showing an exception message of "External component has thrown an exception". I have a couple places that can send out an error email and both of them are triggering, each with a slightly different stack trace provided, which are below.

**Stack Trace 1**

> at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**Stack Trace 2**

> at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult
>   result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String
>   cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode,
>   Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   at ITJobs.MvcApplication.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in C:\projects\Norton VS2015 Modules\ITJobs\ITJobs\Global.asax.cs:line
>   53

Can anyone give me any ideas why this might have suddenly started failing? It works fine when I load it locally via Visual Studio, and is only encountering issues when loading from the remote server.

**EDIT**

I've since tried to redeploy the site and it is now loading something, but i'm getting a server error instead:

```
Compilation Error 

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 255.
```

I'm also getting a different stack trace now too:

> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>D:\inetpub\devnortonitjobs\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\7dde560d\a27d7599_f3a3d201\ITJobs.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\8180ca72\00c8d184_3aaece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\01bc4244\00f33ccc_5616d101\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\f960caeb\001bc110_4318cf01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\66b265c1\00f33ccc_5616d101\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Administration\7.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\976e3ce5\00196fd3_a63ad001\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\dc05fc19\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\df4b3ddd\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\d23b6113\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\07b76d4f\00b31c22_a73ad001\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\c3ba886d\0044d876_ee54d201\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\7f7593fb\0054c7db_a63ad001\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\dfebe864\000f0ccd_bfc5d101\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\assembly\dl3\6a6fa841\00a6d731_3527cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\App_global.asax.fqgak1se.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\App_global.asax.fqgak1se.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b99920d\6bc21d2c\App_global.asax.fqgak1se.1.cs"

Comment: have you tried completely removing the published site and republishing again?

Comment: Did you perform any update on the assemblies?

Comment: @DavidLee I managed to remove most of the files/folders but I couldn't delete a certain folder "aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319". It's empty but won't let me remove it. Republishing after I delete the rest though results in it showing a runtime error now rather than a blank page

Comment: @ngeksyo In the web.config the Microsoft.Json, and WebGrease assemblies have been updated to new versions. Also the Antlr3.Runtime assembly has been added

Comment: @jamespeel are error message aside from the stack trace?

Comment: @ngeksyo I'm getting a compiler error now, just updated the original post with the new information

Comment: @jamespeel try cleaning the files on this folder. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the problem was the Roslyn package that was included in the solution. Deleting the folder from the bin folder, removing the package from the solution, and redeploying fixed the issue.

Thanks to everyone who commented!